# Calculate Percentage on Alias Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Server type: MariaDB Server version: 10.4.16-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution Protocol version: 10

How do I calculate percentage based on the value of and alias column.

```
SELECT REGION, PARTY, SUM(RESULT) AS 'TOTALVOTES',
(TOTALVOTES/SUM(TOTALVOTES)) * 100 AS 'SHARE'
FROM e_presidential
WHERE REGION = "ASHANTI"
GROUP BY PARTY
ORDER BY TOTALVOTES DESC;
```

--
What I gather is I can't do this with an Alias column.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.4.16-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10

Comment: Do you want the percentages for each party by region or just for each party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
SELECT REGION, PARTY, SUM(RESULT) AS TOTALVOTES,
       SUM(RESULT) * 100 / SUM(SUM(RESULT)) OVER () AS SHARE
FROM e_presidential
WHERE REGION = 'ASHANTI'
GROUP BY REGION, PARTY
ORDER BY TOTALVOTES DESC;
```

Note that I included `REGION` in the `GROUP BY`.  I'm surprised your query doesn't generate an error because the `GROUP BY` columns are inconsistent with the unaggregated `SELECT` columns.

If you wanted this for all regions, but the total within the region, then you would want `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT REGION, PARTY, SUM(RESULT) AS TOTALVOTES,
       SUM(RESULT) * 100 / SUM(SUM(RESULT)) OVER (PARTITION BY REGION) AS SHARE
FROM e_presidential
GROUP BY REGION, PARTY
ORDER BY REGION, TOTALVOTES DESC;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=2af539041356c0218649acf3c40476d6) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the alias of a derived column in the same `SELECT` statement to perform any calculations.
If you want the percentage of each party by region use a CTE where you calculate the totals of each region and join to your query:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT region, SUM(result) total_region FROM e_presidential GROUP BY region)
SELECT p.party, p.region,
       SUM(p.result) total_party,
       100 * SUM(p.result) / c.total_region share
FROM e_presidential p INNER JOIN cte c
ON c.region = p.region
GROUP BY party, region
```

If you want the percentage of each party for all regions use a CTE where you calculate the total of all regions and use it in your query:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT SUM(result) total FROM e_presidential)
SELECT party, 
       SUM(result) total_party,
       100 * SUM(result) / (SELECT total FROM cte) share
FROM e_presidential
GROUP BY party
```

Answer (score -1):

We cannot use alias name column in the calculation because that is given by us and logically it is not a column. It can be done by

```
    SELECT REGION, PARTY, SUM(RESULT) AS 'TOTALVOTES',
(SUM(RESULT)/SUM(TOTALVOTES)) * 100 AS 'SHARE'
FROM e_presidential
WHERE REGION = "ASHANTI"
GROUP BY PARTY
ORDER BY TOTALVOTES DESC;
```

This will work fine

Comment: this produced the same error I had. 
Unknown column 'TOTALVOTES' in 'field list